# Batch convert svg to ico, specifying size?

Tags: icons, png, imagemagick, svg

In Windows, I have a GNOME icon theme in the svg format; several svg files residing within subfolders. Is there a way, on the command line, to convert these to ico files with the same name in the same subdirectory, while specifying the output size?

Answer (score 2):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), you can write a batch file with the following contents, which should be placed in the root folder containing the subdirectories with the icons:
`for /R . %%a in (*.svg) do convert -background none -density 256x256 %%a %%~dpna.ico`
Where 256x256 is the desired resolution. If the svg does not support scaling at this size, it will go as high as it can.

Comment: @BenWest No problem! I'd looked for this one a few times, so once I figured it out I figured I'd make it easier for the next person.